# How to align braces with middle vertical line the same size in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, braces

How can I make the middle vertical line the same size as the braces?

```
\[
A\left(c\mid \substack{a,b \\ c,d} \right)
\]
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is not defined command `\c` and the `\substack` does not work properly in your example.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE?

Comment: Thanks Dox, it should be $A\left(c\mid \substack{a,b \\ c,d} \right)$

Comment: I'd use `\Big|` instead of `\mid`... although it is not the nicest solution.

Comment: are you saying that the `\substack`ed expression should be *below* the vertical line?  this doesn't make sense to me.  if you could show a drawing of what you expect, then the question would be easier to answer.  (as phrased, i'd guess that the substack should hang out *below* the braces, and i'm not sure what that means with respect to the "A".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some options - I prefer the use of `\Big` and friends:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  A\left(c\mid \substack{a,b \\ c,d} \right)
\]

\[
  A\Bigl(c\Bigm\vert \substack{a,b \\ c,d} \Bigr) \quad% Preferred
  A\left(c\middle\vert \substack{a,b \\ c,d} \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: i wouldn't even have thought of using `\substack` in this situation; more likely to use a `\genfrac` approach.  that's why i was so confused by the question.  i do think the fences are a bit large; would have tried `\bigg` also, and compared to see which looks better.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of the `\substack` macro appears to be an attempt to re-create the `smallmatrix` environment. I would write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
A\bigl(\, c \: \big\vert \begin{smallmatrix}a,b \\ c,d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Note the use of `\,` and `\:` to adjust the spacing around `c`; since `smallmatrix` automatically inserts a bit of whitespace around it, there's no need to fine-tune the spacing of the material *after* the vertical bar.

Comment: i agree fully that \substack` isn't the best choice here -- it really confused me in the question.

Comment: no, i'm confused.  the progression is `\big`, `\Big`, \bigg`, `\Bigg`.  that comment has been zapped.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the `mathtools` package. Here I define an `\innerp` command (I supposed you tried to make a variable sized inner product) with `two` arguments in `one`, that have to be separated by a semicolon. This last point can be realised with `xparse`. Usage:

- `\innerp` does no scaling;
- `\innerp*` acts as a pair of `\left … \right`;
- for fine-tuning of the size of delimiters, `\innerp[\big]` inserts a pair of `\bigl … \bigr`.

Note that in the rare cases when the argument of `\innerp` must contain a semicolon which comes before the argument separator, you have to add a pair of braces around it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1](){\innerpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innerpargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\innerpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innerpargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#1\:\delimsize\vert\:\mathopen{} #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l >{$}c<{$}}
  \verb+\innerp*+: & \innerp*{c;\substack{a,b \\c,d}}\\[3ex]
  \verb+\innerp[\big]+: & \innerp[\big]{c;\substack{a,b \\c,d}\mkern1.5mu}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if the first arg contains a comma? Does one then always have to remember to protect it in order to hide it from the parser? (This is why I tend to stay away from parsing solutions)

Comment: Yes. However, the comma is often already ‘naturally’ hidden (e.g. because the first argument is the result of a command). An we can use a semi-colon, which much more rarely used in maths formulae, as a separator. I modified my answer in function of your comment.

Comment: I'm still not convinced it is the best syntax for user input. Just because a char might be rare doesn't mean users will not use it. At the moment I don't know what a good interface would be.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no perfect interface: two arguments with two pairs of braces slows down typing and is somewhat unnatural w.r.t. formulae handwriting. Two arguments in one  with a separator is closer, but has the drawback you pointed. The less bad solution, in my opinion, is a rarely used separator (thus it will seldom have to be protected), and easily accessible on a keyboard. In addition, semicolon is one of the  natural separators in handwriting.

Comment: For something as an inner product I find it more natural to make it a two argument macro, because it *is* a two argument function. And adding braces is not that slow. Some editors even just require you to type `{`.

Comment: On a French keyboard, a left brace requires `Ctrl+Alt+4`! My editor allows me to type `Alt+4` to get a pair of braces, with the cursor in-between, but not everybody has that. For the other point, of course it is a two-argument function, but it is often written as `(u,v)`. I think it is mainly a matter of personal routines.

Comment: Ahh, yes the dredded french keyboard. On a Danish one you have to use right alt + 0. There is a reason why I swear by US keyboards. Regarind the `(u.v)` there is still a point in the `,` being configurable and thus taken out of the input syntax.

Comment: What about accented letters on a US keyboard? Maybe it's the reason why some people still type nowadays `d\^{u}` instead of `dû`?

Comment: Using linux + compose key => very large keyboard ;-)